# How to download specific part of html site and store it?

Tags: java, html, parsing

How can I download specific content on a website using Java? I need to go on site and download every url that is stored in a html table in specified class.

I would like to thank you for all the hints I can use for this task!

Comment: Look into selenium

Comment: How about `Jsoup`?

Comment: Do you need this to be done in Java or any scripting lang will do?

Answer (score 0):

You can grab content from another website using for example by htmlUnit or Selenium.